# convert ajax string to array

Tags: html, ajax

I want to convert values that get from ajax into an array, from which I can get values and format them.

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    $('#documenter_nav > li a').click(function(){
     var url = $(this).attr('data-url');

     $.getJSON(url, function(data){
       var html =  "";
       var vlerat =  "";
       var myData = data.content;

       $.each(myData, function(index){
        $.each(myData[index], function(key, value){      
        vlerat += key; 
        html += value;
        });
       });     
       $("#documenter_content").html(vlerat);
      });    
     return false;
    });

   });
```

From what I have done it gives me all keys and values from database as string. I want to get  an array, and display diferent vales of array in different tags of html.

Comment: Deliver your data as JSON in the first place, then you’ll get the data structure you want automatically.

Comment: I want to get them as array, but when I do it with JSON it prints the json array. Please could you edit my code

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax file, store your values into a JSON object.

```
$array = array(
    'value1'=>$value1,
    'value2'=>$value2
    );

echo json_encode($array);
```

and then in your jQuery, you can extract them using something like this...

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url:'ajax url here',
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
});

request.done(function(Response){
    alert(Response.value1);
});
```

Comment: is there any onether way to split the string in an array ? because this is the way I am passing values to jquery as json_encode. But the problem is that it gives me all values for a row in database with an id, and i want to split fields, for example "title", "text" etc